# Pricing a Power Contract derivative security

Tags: options, option-pricing, black-scholes, valuation, risk-neutral-measure

I'm trying to price a "power contract" and would appreciate guidance on the next step. The payoff at time $T$ is $(S(T)/K)^\alpha$, where $K > 0$, $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}$, $T > 0$. $S$ is adapted to $\mathscr{F}$, and we are currently at time $t \in [0,T)$. Let $Q$ denote the risk-neutral measure and $\beta(t) = e^{\int_0^t r(s)ds}$ be the domestic savings account/discount factor. Also, $W(t)$ is standard Brownian Motion.

Here's my progress:

$\displaystyle \ \ \text{value}_t = E^Q[\frac{\beta(t)}{\beta(T)}(S(T)/K)^\alpha \big|\mathscr{F}_t]$

$\displaystyle \ \ = \frac{\beta(t)}{\beta(T)K^\alpha}E^Q[S(T)^\alpha \big|\mathscr{F}_t]$

We take $\displaystyle \ \ S(T)^\alpha = S(t)^\alpha \exp{\{\bigg[ (r-\frac12 \sigma^2)(T-t)+\sigma(W(T)-W(t))\bigg]\alpha  \}}$.

Therefore:

$\displaystyle \ \ \text{value}_t = \frac{\beta(t)S(t)^\alpha}{\beta(T)K^\alpha}\exp{\{ \alpha(r-\frac12 \sigma^2)(T-t) + \frac12 \alpha^2 \sigma^2(T-t)  \}}$

by the fact that $E[e^z] = e^{\mu + \frac12 \sigma^2}$ when $z \sim \mathscr{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$.

---

This is homework but is not graded.

Comment: You should indicate when a question is homework.